# How to add cart to top menu in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Woocommerce for my ecommerce site and need help moving things around. I have the Storefront parent theme with the Homestore child theme. I am loading any additional functions/css/js in the plugin called Theme Customisations recommended by Woocommerce so they are not overwritten.

I would like to move the "Cart" box up to the top right beside the Search box. What function do I use to do this? I have tried multiple things such as:

```
add_action('storefront_after_header', 'cart_second_nav_bar');
function cart_second_nav_bar() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_after_header', 'storefront_header_cart',60 );
    add_action( 'storefront_after_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 10 );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You have to find the hooks where it is and where it will go.  Get the Simply Show Hooks plugin from the repo, turn it on. See where the hook is now and the priority, remove it with the same priority and the remove_action. Then add that back in to the hook area in the top bar or use the same hook for the search bar and up the priority of the search bar by one so that the cart comes after. Learn about hooks, functions, and priorities (in the Codex) so this makes sense.

Comment: You state that you have a Plugin, to load your functions/css/js files as so they do not get overridden.  If you place these files in your Child Theme, they will not be overridden anyway :-)